# ASPNet_RegSQL named instance with port specified

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership

When trying to use ASPNet_RegSQL (v4.0.30319) with a named instance with port specified (i.e. -Sserver\instance,#####), I get the error "The argument '-SMyServer\MyInstance,12345' is invalid.".
Is there a work-around for this issue? This is for connecting to a named instance "in the cloud" that does not provide SQL Browser identification of the port, so a port specification is required.
I am able to use this server specification with sqlcmd.exe successfully. It appears to be a limitation of the ASPNet_RegSQL application.

Trying to run ASPNet_RegSQL with -S specification that includes port number.
Expected it to "work".
Instead got error "The argument '-SMyServer\MyInstance,12345' is invalid."

Comment: No joy: "The argument '-SMyServer,12345' is invalid."

Comment: If you already know the port that the instance is listening on then have you tried... not using an instance name? When you include an instance name the SQL Server Resolution Protocol is invoked to query the SQL Browser service on the target address, via udp/1434, to resolve the instance name to its listening port number. You already know the port number so just bypass that whole process.

Comment: AlwaysLearning...see my "No joy". Tried that and it is just as unsuccessful.

Comment: DOH!! The error had nothing to do with the values, but rather the syntax. Note that there is no space between the "-S" and the value.